# Logisim flashing button

Tags: clock, button, logisim

How can I create a button with a clock that is connected to a LED so that the LED turns on when the button is pressed, but if you keep holding it it will turn off?

Comment: do not turn the led on if the button is pressed ... turn it on when the button transitions

Answer (score 0):

Build an edge detector. It can as simple as this:

[image: Edge detector]

Since Logisim doesn't have a monoflop you need to use the clock generator to generate time events. The D-FF stores the level of your input. ANDing the input with the inverted delayed input gives you a short pulse each time you raise the level from 0 to 1.

This pulse has varying duration depending when the input raising edge happens in respect to the clock edge. If you need a pulse of equal duration synchronize the input with another D-FF before feeding it into this circuit.